# Connecting to a wifi network with Android 9 (API level 28)

Tags: android, react-native

I've been working on a react-native application recently, and I'd like to connect the devices to a wifi network through the app. I used the [react-native-wifi](https://github.com/blackdeve/react-native-wifi) npm lib to achieve this but it seems i have some problems connection with my android 9 phone. Although the lib is working with an other phone which is running **android 7.1 (Nougat).**

The **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** permission is granted in *runtime*  by the user, also **ACCESS_WIFI_STATE** and **CHANGE_WIFI_STATE** are granted in the manifest.

So the native module that is used is:

```java
public Boolean connectTo(ScanResult result, String password, String ssid, Promise promise) {
        //Make new configuration
        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            conf.SSID = ssid;
        } else {
            conf.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
        }

        String capabilities = result.capabilities;

        if (capabilities.contains("WPA") ||
                capabilities.contains("WPA2") ||
                capabilities.contains("WPA/WPA2 PSK")) {

            // appropriate ciper is need to set according to security type used,
            // ifcase of not added it will not be able to connect
            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
            conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + password + "\"";

        } else if (capabilities.contains("WEP")) {
            conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + password + "\"";
            conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);

        } else {
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        }

        //Remove the existing configuration for this netwrok
        List<WifiConfiguration> mWifiConfigList = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();

        int updateNetwork = -1;

        for (WifiConfiguration wifiConfig : mWifiConfigList) {
            if (wifiConfig.SSID.equals(conf.SSID)) {
                conf.networkId = wifiConfig.networkId;
                updateNetwork = wifi.updateNetwork(conf);
            }
        }

        // If network not already in configured networks add new network
        if (updateNetwork == -1) {
            updateNetwork = wifi.addNetwork(conf);
            wifi.saveConfiguration();
        }

        if (updateNetwork == -1) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean disconnect = wifi.disconnect();
        if (!disconnect) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean enableNetwork = wifi.enableNetwork(updateNetwork, true);
        if (!enableNetwork) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

(returning false means the connection didnt succeed)

I was debugging it and it seems that **`wifi.updateNetwork(conf)`** and **`wifi.addNetwork(conf)`** always return **-1** no matter what (so far). By the android docs these methods should still work with the API level 28.

I'm trying to connect to a WPA2 network. Also i tried to remove the network from the **`wifi.getConfiguredNetworks()`** list but didn't change anything.

I don't know what i'm missing, but i'd be really happy if somebody could help me out with this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all i managed to find the solution which is really simple, just had to quote the ssid and it works. Tested on API level 27 and 28.